# how to add a wildcard to an xmlstarlet update

Tags: attributes, wildcard, xmlstarlet

This xmlstartlet update works for "ThreadGroup" but not for "fooThreadGroup" how can I add a prefix wildcard to the string "ThreadGroup" in the following please?

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace --update '//ThreadGroup/longProp[@name="ThreadGroup.start_time"]' --value '1363247040000' "${xmlFile}"
```

Comment: what is `"fooThreadGroup"` in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Since xmlstarlet doesn't support `ends-with()` (because that's XPath 2.0), you'd have to do something like:

```
//*[self::ThreadGroup or self::fooThreadGroup]/longProp[@name="ThreadGroup.start_time"]
```